# JavaScript forEach: How can I count the number of lines written by the forEach function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, proxies

Currently my code is:

```
var ProxyVerifier = require('proxy-verifier');
const fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
const { doesNotMatch } = require('assert');

let config = {
    file: 'socks4_proxies.txt',
    destFile: 'result.txt'
}

function countFileLines(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let lineCount = 0;
        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .on("data", (buffer) => {
                let idx = -1;
                lineCount--; // Because the loop will run once for idx=-1
                do {
                    idx = buffer.indexOf(10, idx + 1);
                    lineCount++;
                } while (idx !== -1);
            }).on("end", () => {
                resolve(lineCount);
            }).on("error", reject);
    });
};

function getProxies() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get('https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=displayproxies&proxytype=socks4&timeout=2500', function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
                console.log('Proxies pulled!')
            } else {
                console.log(`Oops, ProxyScrape is down! Please try again later / contact me`)
            }
        });
    });
}

async function proxyTestLogic(proxy_list, index) {
    var countLines = await countFileLines('file.txt')
    console.log(index)
    if (index > 150) {
        console.log('Ok good done you can stop now')
        return 'stop';
    } else {
        var splitProxy = proxy_list.split(':');
        var ipPortArr = [splitProxy[0], Number(splitProxy[1])]
        var proxy = {
            ipAddress: ipPortArr[0],
            port: ipPortArr[1],
            protocol: 'socks4'
        };

        ProxyVerifier.testAll(proxy, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
            } else {
                if (result["protocols"]["socks4"]["ok"] == true) {
                    fs.appendFile('file.txt', ipPortArr[0] + ':' + ipPortArr[1] + '\n', (err) => {
                    });
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function testProxies(proxies) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let newLined = proxies.replace(/\r|\"/gi, '').split("\n")
        newLined.forEach((item, index) => {
            proxyTestLogic(item, index)
        })
    })
}

async function main() {
    let proxies = await getProxies();
    testProxies(proxies)
}

main();
```

As you can see, it's a proxy verifier. It uses the forEach function to compute each proxy in an array. I'm trying to get it to stop at x amount of lines written to socks4_proxies.txt, when I enable the console.log function on it, it just outputs the same line 1200 times (the amount of proxies in the list). How can I fix this?

(I should also mention that I'm coding in node.js)

Thanks,
JIBSIL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't do asynchronous code in a `.forEach`, that never works like you expect - use a regular for loop
2. make `tetProxies` async
3. use `await proxytestLogic`
4. get rid of that `new Promise` you never resolve anyway

so - you end up with:

```
async function testProxies(proxies) {
    let newLined = proxies.replace(/\r|\"/gi, '').split("\n")
    for (let index=0; i < newLined.length; index++) {
            let result = await proxyTestLogic(newLined[index], index);
            if (result === 'stop')
                break;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was too slow. Exact reason is that you call `forEach` handler as many times as the count of proxies there are.

Comment: @AndreyPopov - and you never can "wait" for each iteration to complete before starting the next one!

Comment: I'd go even further saying that since we just check the `index` passed to `proxyTestLogic`, then there's no need to wait for it or anything. It should be something like `for (let index = 0; index < 150; index++)`... That's all :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov - not so sure about that - the lines is calcualted in the call to `proxyTestLogic` - and can be more than one for each ... the stop condition is when that function resolve to `stop` - edit: no, wait, yes ... I see that now, I misunderstood the code in that function (didn't really look too hard to be honest as `testProxies` was an obvious hot mess!!!

Comment: There's this line `if (index > 150) {`, so it's just hardcoded ;) There's no calculation being done on when to stop - it's at 150.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'